# How to click a webpage button without going on the webpage

Tags: python, html, automation, click

I am attempting to semi-automate my department's workflow, and part of it includes this project I'm doing. The sections I am currently struggling with is "clicking" a button on a webpage.

The webpage has data in a grid (looks like an Excel sheet) and has multiple pages that I want to parse out and use as data for the automation, and there is a button on the webpage that, when clicked, converts all the pages of that data into an Excel sheet and saves it where I need on my computer. I want to constantly update that Excel sheet with the changes as more data is added to the webpage.

However, I do not want to always have that webpage open and have automatic button presses that constantly saves the webpage to Excel. Rather, I want to have it running "in the background" so the only progress I see is the Excel sheet getting updated. Is there a way to "click" that 'Convert to Excel' button without actually going on the webpage to do it?

I was looking at Python libraries like Requests and bs4, but I'm not sure which methods might be applicable for this, if those are even what I should be looking for.

Comment: excel has VBS script in the developer options, write a function that does the script locally using a button within excel.

Comment: @aaronlilly I can create a button in Excel that will click the button on the webpage?

Comment: you can create a button in excel that will run a script the same that a webpage would do, would need to duplicate the script and repeat it in VBS to my understanding,

Answer (score 4):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://example.com")
button = driver.find_element_by_id('buttonID')
button.click()
```

Comment: Selenium driver opens the specified webpage. I'm trying to not have the browser open. Unless Selenium can have a webdriver open without actually having the page open. If so, I didn't know that

Comment: You can run that python code as a cron job so it runs at every set interval you define.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a robot and for Python I highly recommend looking into Selenium. Just google for `python selenium tutorial` or start by reading this: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage